# Negative angle in radians

Tags: angle

I compute an angle of a vector in radians and it is negative (<0, for example _ -5, -150..)

I am going to use cordic to compute sin and cos.

For cordic I use the full circle ( 0 - 360), positive radian values

In degree I can add 360° to convert the angle. For example, -30 : -30+360 = 320°

How can I convert negative radians ?

Comment: The [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) is $2 \pi \text { rad} = 360°$

Answer (score 1):

CORDIC algorithm is intended for being used in $[0,\pi/2]$, or even $[0,\pi/4]$ ; it is always possible by trigonometric transformations (think to relationships $\sin(-a)=-\sin(a), \sin(\pi/2-a)=\cos(a)$, etc.) not to bother with larger ranges in particular not to consider negative quantities either in radians or degrees.